# Trying to get into replace() instances such as "34-45"

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out a way to use the replace() function to find strings such as "23-34". So far Iv'e been using the following code for similar purposes, and Id'e like to keep using the function replace (nevermind that it doesn't do anything yet).

```
function Work() {
    function PleaseWork(match) {
        var x = +match + 408;
        x = ' ' + x;
        return x;
    }
    document.getElementById("InputText").value = document.getElementById("InputText").value.replace(/\s+\d+/g, PleaseWork);
}
```

Iv'e tried to replace the expression `/\s+\d+/g` with `/\d+\-\d+/g`. But unfortunately that won't run or won't result in taking away the instances I need it to take.

Any advises?

Comment: You usually use `replace` method to *remove* something, and `match`/`exec` to *find* something. Why use replace? Note that right now the question sounds rather unclear.

Comment: Replace function is actually very useful in doing... replacing. :-)

Comment: Can you comment on what your input and your expected output is?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to replace (input -> output)?

Comment: Input is something like this:
23-5,34-5, 343, 344

Out put should be an array that looks something like this:
[(23,5),(34,5)]

Comment: So input is a single string, and output should be nested arrays?

Comment: You want match() not replace(), match returns an array with the matches.

Comment: the array should be [(23,5)] in the first run of the function and then [(34,5)] in the second. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: [edit] your question to include the desired input and output.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is a valid answer:

```js
function Work() {
  function PleaseWork(match) {
    // this is your array:  match.split('-')
    return '[' + match.split('-') + ']';
  }
  document.getElementById("InputText").value = document.getElementById("InputText").value.replace(/\d+-\d+|\d+/g, PleaseWork);
}
```

Comment: It worked half way in one run. can you explain me what the logic behind you regex?

Comment: @EliRotenberg find 23-5 or 343  in regex \d+-\d+|\d+. It's ok my answer?

Comment: Actually now it worked good (I have some problems with my chrome). Can you explain the thought procces behind the regex still? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You want match() not replace(), match returns an array with the matches.

Also, beware of the minus key vs dash key.  They are different values on the ASCII table.

Comment: I want replace because I need to do some manipulation on the array and then put it back exactly where ive found it.